# inspect.ismethod() returns false for the instance method in the decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to detect whether a function is instance method or it is module level function inside the python decorator using the inspect.ismethod(). It returns false for that. what is the reason? How do I detect whether the function is instance method or the module level function inside the decorator like below.

Example:

```
import inspect
class A(object):
  @deco("somearg")
  def sample(self):
      print "abc"

a = A()
print inspect.ismethod(a.sample) # Returns True
```

Above print returns true.

My decorator is something like below. I need to pass the arguments to decorator in the actual code so it's inside the function:

```
def deco(some_arg=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print some_arg
            print inspect.ismethod(func)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Above inspect.ismethod() returns false.

My python version is 2.7.13

Comment: That's because your `wrapper` function becomes the method here, when the class is finalized. The function it wraps is still a function. There's no way to know what you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

> Note that the transformation from function object to (unbound or
>   bound) method object happens each time the attribute is retrieved from
>   the class or instance.

What you're decorating is a function. And functions nested in classes are still functions. It classifies as a method when you access the function from the class or an instance of the class.

You can instead access the method object from the `self` parameter in your `wrapper`:

```
def deco(some_arg=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print some_arg
            print inspect.ismethod(args[0].sample) 
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```